# A rich text editor that allows selectionStart and selectionEnd

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, selection-api

I am trying to implement an interface, where there is a Rich Text Editor (RTE) and a panel on the side which allows the user to introduce certain code snippets into the RTE.

What I am trying is exactly like http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/wPfVn/ only that I want to do it with an RTE instead of a plain textarea.

The problem is that all RTE's replace the textarea with divs and iframes etc. The textarea functions like `selectStart` and `selectionEnd` are not available to detect the cursor position.

Is there an RTE which exposes such functions via an API which I can use?

If anyone has seen something like this on some site, please point me to it. Maybe I can ctrl+u and figure out what they've used.

SOLVED:
Thanks to the answer by Magus. One can use TinyMCE editor. It has a concept of selection and selection.bookmarks. Here is how you can achieve the result.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "notifierBody",           
});
$('.insertBtn').click(function(){
    // Stores a bookmark of the current selection
    var bm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();
    // Restore the selection bookmark. In effect, takes the control that the bookmark
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(bm);
    //Add new content right in the middle where your cursor/selection was
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('Some new content');  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) gots some API for the current selection. Look at the documentation : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.dom.Selection

A little example :

```
tinyMce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : 'raw'}); // Get the selected text
tinyMce.activeEditor.selection.getStart(); // Selection start
tinyMce.activeEditor.selection.getEnd(); // Selection end
```

I think many RTE provide this functions. You just have to look the API documentation.